# I cannot seem to connect to Firestore database to save user's data

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on an Android project and I've been stuck with this problem for a few hours now.

I'm trying to connect to my Firestore database. The idea is to store documents with additional info from the users. It's created on-register and then sent to the database.

Here's the code:

```
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Sign in success
                Log.d("RegistroFirebase", "createUserWithEmail:success")
                val user = auth.currentUser

                // Create user's database document

                writeNewUser(
                    user!!.uid, user!!.email, binding.signUpName.text.toString(),
                    binding.signUpSurname.text.toString(), "623623623")
                    Log.d("Crear documento usuario", "Success?")

                reload("main")`
```

And the function:

```
private fun writeNewUser(userId: String, email: String?, name: String, surname: String, phone:String) {
    val user = User(email, name, surname, phone)

    db.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user)
}
```

Also I have a class for users:

```
data class User(val email:String? = null, val name:String? = null,
                val surname:String? = null, val phone:String? = null) {}
```

As for the error, I get none. It just works but it doesn't add anything new to my Firestore 'user' collection.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried Abdullah Z Khan's solution? Does it work?

Comment: No it doesn't. It just seems that the program is not executing that line. However, thanks to that I noticed something new from the logcat. It's on the question now.

Comment: Have you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly?

Comment: If [this](https://imgur.com/a/bKn24oQ) is what you're talking about, then yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say:

> I cannot seem to connect to Firestore database to save user's data

And it makes sense, since when using the following lines of code:

```
val user = User(email, name, surname, phone)
db.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user)
```

You are trying to write data to the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database) and **not** to [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore). While both, databases are a part of Firebase services, they are different databases with different mechanisms. To be able to write data to Firestore, please use the following line of code:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference usersRef = db.collection("users");
usersRef.document(userId).set(user)
```

You can also attach a listener to the complete operation, to see if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to user creation, the `setValue` function can also be listened to with `addOnCompleteListener`, `addOnSuccessListener`, `addOnFailureListener`.

Ref: [Add a Completion Callback](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback).

You need to diagnose the result through these.

Comment: I've tested with this to check and get some errors. It shows none of my outputs for each outcome, but I've noticed this line on the logcat: 
`2021-11-16 13:56:25.826 12534-12665/com.example.senato W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Firebase error. Please ensure that you spelled the name of your Firebase correctly`